# Is it normal to find mistakes in the novel “Lord of Flies”?

Tags: informal-language, register

I started reading “Lord of Flies” from William Golding, and so far I really like it.

However, I came across many grammar or verb mistakes like the ones below:

“Your dad don’t know, nobody don’t know...”
“We was attacked”

I know the dialogues are maintained with 12-year-olds, so I wonder if it’s on purpose.

Comment: That is not a mistake. It's a sociolect and shows the boy is not upper or middle class: He is working class.

Comment: @Lambie - This sounds like a great answer. Why don’t you add some descriptions, definitions, and/or examples, and add it to the Answer section. I would upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

You have it right in your last line. It's a mistake, but the author didn't do it by accident; he is writing a character who speaks with poor grammar.

Comment: It's ***not*** a mistake. It's an accurate reflection of their speech. From an idiomatic speech perspective, it's quite correct in terms of their social and cultural position. For them, it might be a mistake to *not* speak that way.